# How can I save a checkpoint to path using Keras?

Tags: keras

How can I save a checkpoint in Keras and use it for callbacks?

The file will need to be an .h5 model.

Comment: what do you mean save it for callbacks? What's the problem with the ModelCheckpoint callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the path directory of your .h5 model, as well as define the parameters for your checkpoint.
My recommendation would be to `monitor= val_acc` and setting the save_best_only to True.

```py
filepath="model.h5"
checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint1]
```